# Insert blank columns into csv with Powershell

Tags: powershell

In my script, I am building a custom Powershell object which will be sent to Export-Csv. The receiving party has required that I include some blank columns (no data and no header) and I have no idea how to do that.

If the object looks like this:

```
$obj = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    EMPLOYER_EIN               = '123456'
    ACTION_CODE                = 1
    LAST_NAME                  = Smith
    FIRST_NAME                 = John
    MIDDLE_INITIAL             = $null
    EMPLOYEE_SSN               = '111-11-1111'
}
```

How can I have the resulting .csv file's first row look like this:

> EMPLOYER_EIN,ACTION_CODE,,LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INITIAL,,EMPLOYEE_SSN

Put another way, after I run Export-Csv, I want the file to look like this when opened in Excel:

| EMPLOYER_EIN | ACTION_CODE |  | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | MIDDLE_INITIAL |  | EMPLOYEE_SSN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1 |  | Smith | John |  |  | 111-11-1111 |

Note the extra columns between action_code/last_name and middle_initial/employee_ssn. I am using PS 5.1 but could use 7 if necessary.

Comment: Like `$headers = $obj | ConvertTo-Csv | Select-Object -First 1` ?

Comment: No, there will be multiple rows in the .csv. This example codes just shows one of them. If I run `$obj | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation`, then I get a normal .csv file. But I need the resulting file to have extra columns. I need a blank column between ACTION_CODE and LAST_NAME and another between MIDDLE_INITIAL and EMPLOYEE_SSN.

Comment: so you're asking to update all rows to fit the new headers basically

Comment: Do you care if there are headers for the blank columns? Like `$obj | Select EMPLOYER_EIN,ACTIONCODE,@{l='BLANK1';e={}},LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_INITIAL,@{l='BLANK2';e={}},EMPLOYEE_SSN | Export-Csv C:\Path\To\File.csv -NoType`

Comment: The extra columns need to be completely empty. I updated my original post with a visual example.

Comment: From powershell, your best bet will be to use white space property names i.e. `[pscustomobject]@{ '   ' = $null }`

Comment: Is it acceptable if the header for the "blank" column is a single space?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, I can only do that for one "filler" column. Adding more than one, Powershell throws an error because you have to identical "properties"

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, Yes, that's fine...as far as I know

Comment: Well yes, you add 1 more space for each "blank" property..

Comment: Hmm...that could work. I will have to verify with the recipient.

Comment: As an aside: you don't need `[ordered]` in a `[pscustomobject]` literal - the order is _implicitly_ preserved (syntactic sugar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

- constructing the object with blank dummy properties with a shared name prefix, such as `BLANK_`, followed by a sequence number (the property names must be unique)
- initially piping to [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv), which allows use of a [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation to replace the dummy property names with empty strings in the first output line (the header line).
- the result - which already is in CSV format - can then be saved to a CSV file with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content).

```bash
$obj = [PSCustomObject] @{
  EMPLOYER_EIN               = '123456'
  ACTION_CODE                = 1
  BLANK_1                    = $null    # first dummy property
  LAST_NAME                  = 'Smith'
  FIRST_NAME                 = 'John'
  MIDDLE_INITIAL             = $null
  BLANK_2                    = $null    # second dummy property
  EMPLOYEE_SSN               = '111-11-1111'
}

$first = $true
$obj | 
  ConvertTo-Csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($first) { # header row: replace dummy property names with empty string
      $first = $false
      $_ -replace '\bBLANK_\d+'
    }
    else { # data row: pass through
      $_
    }
  } # pipe to Set-Content as needed.
```

Output (note the blank column names after `ACTION CODE` and `MIDDLE_INITIAL`):

```bash
"EMPLOYER_EIN","ACTION_CODE","","LAST_NAME","FIRST_NAME","MIDDLE_INITIAL","","EMPLOYEE_SSN"
"123456","1",,"Smith","John",,,"111-11-1111"
```

Answer (score 2):

As a test, I created a CSV `test.csv` with fields `A`,`B`, and `C`, and put a couple of lines of values:

```
"A","B","C"
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

I then executed the sequence of commands

```
Import-CSV -path Test.csv | Select-Object -Prop A," ",B,C | Export-CSV -Path test2.csv
```

and looked at the resultant `test2.csv`, which contained

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"A"," ","B","C"
"1",,"2","3"
"4",,"5","6"
```

I believe that this is going to be the closest you'll get without manually processing the CSV as a text file.

This is essentially what Santiago Squarzon was suggesting in the comments.

If you need multiple "blank" columns, each one will have to have a header with a different non-zero number of spaces.

Comment: Obviously, I forgot the `-NoTypeInformation` for the `Export-CSV`, but it's still good enough to illustrate the technique...

Comment: That only works for one "filler" column. When I add the second one, PS says, "Select-Object : The property cannot be processed because the property " " already exists.". I will check with the recipient if I can have each "filler" column contain one more blank space than the one before it.

Comment: @StackExchangeGuy - Use `" "` for the first null column, `"  "` for the second, `"   "` for the third, _et cetera_.